# Potential Multiple installations of Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer

I ran into the following problem: I need to supply the installation package to the client. Part of the code is python, so I have to make sure that it is installed. I am using NSIS for the installation ans would like to install python into a predefined by me folder (let it be c:\Program Files\Project\Python26). For that I downloaded the python's msi and trying to execute the following to install it

```
msiexec  /package "$INSTDIR\packages\python-2.6.5.msi" /quiet TARGETDIR=c:\Program Files\Project\Python26
```

This works the first time (when python is not already installed), but if the python is already installed, I have to choose between reinstalling/repairing/changing. Does anybody know how to make sure that I can install python in the my directory without affecting potentially installed python?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true), options such as `/p` (or maybe `/o` or `/c`, depending on your exact intent) should serve your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer, but I guess I need to clarify - if Python is already installed - I DO NOT want to do anything with it, option p/o/c will reinstall python - I want original python be intact and just install the new one(I do not need to update registry keys - they will not be since I am using /quiet, or add it to PATH variable). Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Sergey, you're wrong: `/p` is documented (in the URL I already gave) as "Reinstalls only if file is missing." -- so **if** there's an "original python", i.e. it is **not** missing, `/p` will indeed make `msiexec` "leave it alone", just as you wish.  The other options can fix previous installs that are present but somehow damaged (e.g. have the wrong checksum, for `/c`), which makes sense to be since if that happens it means they have been broken, therefore are **not** intact but shattered -- but if you're somehow magically certain that, if present, they're intact, then `/p` works for you, no?

Comment: I think when you give `TARGETDIR` option files are checked in the folder you gave. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense because you could end up with some files in the original installation folder and others in the `TARGETDIR`. If it's the case then `/p` does not solve OP's problem.